Is it a good idea to buy a used HVAC? if do, what should I know
Someone is selling their HVAC on marketplace because they plan to remodel the house. The seller says it has only been used for like 5-6 years and runs well. (I couldn't test it as the power is already done. )They will get someone take it off from the house.
Anyone has experience buying a used HVAC before? Would contractors install used HVAC and how much they might charge for a used AC installation (in CA)? What should I know during the disassembly and installation process? Thanks a lot!
The seller says they sell it because they are extending the house for more rooms. Therefore, they might need a new AC. However, only the AC, not furnace.
Also, my house was built after 2000. I believe it has ducts as I have furnace and heating.

Get it checked by a good contractor. As for finding a contractor prepared to install it > find one - use the phone... Obviously they won't guarantee it like a new one so have a slush fund.

the installation would be the same for new or used. How about the heat exchanger cabinet in the home ? What model is it ? Check the label

agree to only pay after you have it installed and verified functioning.

https://www.forbes.com/home-improvement/hvac/ac-installation-cost/#average_cost_of_ac_installation_section

@Traveler not fair to dump on the contractor the issue of faulty equipment, that surely is an issue for the homeowner when they buy secondhand cr*p...

Summary: the cost of moving it, plus the 6 year reduction in service life through which you ammortize the labor charges, plus the lack of any warranty, make this a bad idea.  Don't do it.

Get two or three recommended local installers to each write two quotes.
Quote 1 is to inspect the old system, move it to your house, and install it without a warranty.  Note this installation still requires new coolant lines, electricals, footing for the compressor, cutting in to the existing ductwork, plus the moving cost
Quote 2 is for all-new.
My guess is you'll find at best a 15% cost saving, probably less, for which you get no warranty, likely problems, and will need to replace the system at best 5 years sooner which will blow away any cost saving through duplicated labor cost.

my guess is you'll have to call 20 to find 3 willing to do it

I got a rehab AC once, but it was only because I pulled a favor from one of my subs. He hated doing it.

@AloysiusDefenestrate if you are a contractor or a homeowner with sufficient knowledge, access to cheap labor, and a fridgy sub willing to help, and to put their name on the building permit while you and your cheap peeps do most of the work, that changes the equation.  A lot.  But then also you can buy new components at online prices and get full warranty from your friendly sub's part in the process ... So .. the math needs to be done.  Not by me. :)
